# leakscanary : FrameLayout leaked

Tags: android, memory-leaks

i found a memory leaks in my android app

and when i used leakcanary library

its gave me this error but i dont know what exactly making this error

so ... the error title was .. FrameLayout leaked

and the Error was in a Fragment called

SentFragment.view

and the error is

```
* Instance of com.e7kyy.e7kyy.Fragments.SentFragment
| mAdapter = com.e7kyy.e7kyy.Fragments.SentFragment$1@321628672 (0x132baa00)
| mAuth = com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzj@315228480 (0x12ca0140)
| mBanner = com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView@319033344 (0x13041000)
| mDb = com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference@321575904 (0x132adbe0)
| mId = "CN2OaNldF8ReuvkV5KrTjpD1KwU2"
| mInterstitialAd = null
| mNullUsers = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView@319249408 (0x13075c00)
| mRecyclerView = android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView@319257600 (0x13077c00)
| mUser = com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference@321626944 (0x132ba340)
| view = android.widget.FrameLayout@319031296 (0x13040800)
| mAdded = false
| mAnimationInfo = null
| mArguments = null
| mBackStackNesting = 2
| mCalled = true
| mChildFragmentManager = android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl@316844400 (0x12e2a970)
| mChildNonConfig = null
| mContainer = null
| mContainerId = 2131230865
| mDeferStart = false
| mDetached = false
| mFragmentId = 2131230865
| mFragmentManager = android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl@315234336 (0x12ca1820)
| mFromLayout = false
| mHasMenu = false
| mHidden = false
| mHiddenChanged = false
| mHost = android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@315448448 (0x12cd5c80)
| mInLayout = false
| mIndex = 0
| mInnerView = null
| mIsCreated = true
| mIsNewlyAdded = false
| mLayoutInflater = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater@318294720 (0x12f8cac0)
| mLifecycleRegistry = android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry@318050048 (0x12f50f00)
| mMenuVisible = true
| mParentFragment = null
| mPerformedCreateView = false
| mPostponedAlpha = 0.0
| mRemoving = true
| mRestored = false
| mRetainInstance = false
| mRetaining = false
| mSavedFragmentState = null
| mSavedViewState = android.util.SparseArray@321629312 (0x132bac80)
| mState = 1
| mTag = null
| mTarget = null
| mTargetIndex = -1
| mTargetRequestCode = 0
| mUserVisibleHint = true
| mView = null
| mViewModelStore = android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelStore@318487968 (0x12fbbda0)
| mWho = "android:fragment:0"
| shadow$_klass_ = com.e7kyy.e7kyy.Fragments.SentFragment
| shadow$_monitor_ = 0
```

so how can i know where is the error

or at least what is causing it

thank u :)

Comment: Check the chain of reference which caused the issue instead of looking into one reference!

Comment: My problem was when I used FragmentManager from Activity instead of .getChildFragmentManager() https://proandroiddev.com/android-fragments-common-queries-common-mistakes-df2014da0b50